# Is there a way to implement styles on dynamically generated div inside a component in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox, jsx

In React, I have a component called DivHelper which generates 2 divs one below the other - instead i want to place them side by side and I cant see the code of Divhelper generates the divs. Is there a way to access dynamically generated divs ?

For example -

///Some random code

< DivHelper/>

///Some more code

This becomes

///Some random code

`<div>1 Div</div>`

`<div>2 Div</div>`

///Some more code

and thus, the output is

1 Div

2 Div

Instead I want it to be placed on side by side reversed (like float)
2 Div     1 Div

Is this possible ?

Comment: It is possible, but it depends on the context. Could you share for example your DivHelper component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically change the className of your components in React.
With your CSS you can then style the component and the layout as you want.

For example:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [display, setDisplay] = useState("row");

  const handleClick = () => {
    display === "row" ? setDisplay("column") : setDisplay("row");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Dynamic display</h1>
      <button onClick={() => handleClick()}>Change display</button>
      <div className={"container " + display}>
        <div className="square red">First div</div>
        <div className="square green">Second div</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And your CSS file:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.row {
  flex-direction: row;
}

.column {
  flex-direction: column;
}
.square {
  background: "red";
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.red {
  background: #f00;
}
.green {
  background: #0f0;
}
```